# Errors in Swift - Expected Declaration and Value of type "x" has no member "y" (Image attached)

Tags: swift

Very new to swift and coding in general and am trying to do a basic login/register page for my application.  I'm following along with an online tutorial and (as far as i'm aware) done everything exactly the same.  However, I am receiving two errors when attempting to build and I can't for the life of me figure it out! Any help would be great, thanks.

[Image of all code for this page including errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F73HR.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add the relevant parts of your code to your question instead of posting a screenshot of code. A screenshot of your Storyboard is fine though.

Comment: Hi, thank you.  I will be sure to do this in the future.  Again, I apologise for the ambiguity in the post - as I stated, I am very new to swift and this was my first post on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First error :

```
let userName = someUserNameLabel.text
let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
userDefaults.setValue(userName, forKey: "userName")
userDefaults.synchronize() // don't forget this!!!!
```

Second error:

```
 // Create the alert controller
var alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Registration Successful", preferredStyle: .Alert)

// Create the actions
var okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) {
    UIAlertAction in
    NSLog("OK Pressed")
}

// Add the actions
alertController.addAction(okAction)

// Present the controller
self.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: Thank you! All sorted, very useful!

Comment: @anickson mark question as answer, so everyone can see it :)

Answer (score 0):

Second error: Swift 3 update

```
let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Registration Successful", preferredStyle: .alert)
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default) {
     print("OK Pressed")
}
alertController.addAction(okAction)
self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
```